# How to get an object out of a useState array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I have a table with a row that has a checkbox, and I have an object called an ellipse.

I need to make the ellipse object to enter the `savedEllipse` array (which uses useState) as soon as I click on the checkbox.

In the test I did, I see that the ellipse object did go into the array, but now I have to make it out of the array once I uncheck the checkbox, and I couldn't quite figure out how I could do that with an object type like the ellipse object I have here.

You can see that I did the same thing with setChekcedState, which makes sure that the name of the checkbox comes in and out of the checkedState array, and it works great, but when I tried to do it with the ellipse object the same way, it did not work.

Do you have an idea?

I found (here in StackOverflow) a few questions that are close to this, but none of them dealt with this specific problem, so don't get confused

Here's the code:

```
export default function App() {

const [checkedState, setChekcedState] = useState([]);

const [savedEllipse, setSavedEllipse] = useState([]);

const ellipse = {
  a: [12, 22],
  b: [22, 55],
  c: [42, 68]
};

const ellipseSet = (e) => {
        const { checked, name } = e.target;
        if (checked) {
            setChekcedState((oldState) => [...oldState, name]);
            setCheckedEllipse((oldState) => [...oldState, ellipse]);
        } else {
            setChekcedState((oldState) => oldState.filter((row) => row !== name));
        }
};

return (

<TableContainer>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableBody >
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                <Checkbox
                  onChange={ellipseSet}
                  checked={checkedState.includes((row.id).toString())}
                  name={1}/>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );  
}
```

Comment: It is a unclear what you are trying to achieve. Right now you are pushing the name of the checkbox which is 1 into the checkedState array. And you are trying to push an object variable using setCheckedEllipse which does not exist in your code nor object. You only have provided ellipse object. Even if you want to push ellipse object inside savedEllipse variable you will not able to delete it because you don't habe any distinguisher to use to filter  savedEllipse array

Comment: You are right. I had a trrible mistake. i replaced 'ellipse' with 'object'. try to read the code now

Comment: im trying to delete the 'ellipse' object from the savedEllipse array after im clicking the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these 2 functions to check the equality of the objects

```
 function isEqual(object1, object2) {
      return arrayEquals(object1.a,object2.a) && arrayEquals(object1.b,object2.b) && arrayEquals(object1.c,object2.c);
    }

function arrayEquals(a, b) {
    return Array.isArray(a) &&
        Array.isArray(b) &&
        a.length === b.length &&
        a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}
```

Then we can set the state in ellipse list :)

```
setCheckedEllipse((oldState) => oldState.filter((row) => !isEqual(row,ellipse));
```